# Call to a member function append()

Tags: adminhtml

I am getting an error

`Call to a member function append()....Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php on line 122`
.  I have worked out it is down to my indexAction in the controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('prefs/adminhtml_forms'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

So I have taken a look at the origin of the error

```
protected function _addContent(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    return $this;
}
```

I see it requires a block that has to be `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and the block I am calling is `Mage_Adminhtml_block_Widget_Grid_Container`, however digging down I find `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` is the being extended.

[image]

So I'm now left with the question, what have I done wrong and how do I resolve it?

```
class Ps_Prefs_Block_Adminhtml_Forms
extends Mage_Adminhtml_block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_forms';//path to block
    $this->_blockGroup = 'prefs';//module name
    $this->_headerText = $this->__( 'Form Fields' );
    $this->_addButtonLabel = $this->__( 'New Field' );
    parent::_construct();
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
            $this->_controller . '.grid' )->setSaveParametersInSession( TRUE ) );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this line

```
$this->loadLayout();
```

before

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('prefs/adminhtml_forms'));
```

In your case the layout is not loaded and there is no block with the name content. That's why

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')
```

returns null and you cannot call `null->append()`.